# How i make a custom sql query for Woocommerce

Tags: query, woocommerce-offtopic, sql

hello i have an ecommerce with Wordpress + Woocommerce, just yesterday a hacker boy or...i don't know moved all woocommerce products in to the trash....
there are lots of products and default wordpress bulk edit didn't work propelly,

so i think make a custom slq query for edit wp_posts table and post_status from trash to publish, how i can do it, any help please?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not good at SQL but I believe this SQL query will do the job for you.

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_status = 'publish' 
WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'trash';
```

Please remember to change WP database prefix if it is not default `wp`.

Comment: work great thank you! But after all products restored no category assigned in front end, categories assigned ony i back-end.... how i can fix it?

Comment: fix after  permalinks saved

Answer (score 0):

Save the file into your Plugin directory, and from admin panel, activate the plugin. On activation this will query for all the WooCommerce products with `post_status` `trash` and update them with status `publish`.

**Please test the plugin first in your end, and then apply to the live site.**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Trash Recovery
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/218859/22728
 */

/**
 * Trash retrival for WooCommerce
 * @return void
 */
function wpse218859_trash_to_publish_on_activation() {
    $prod_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                    'post_type'         => 'product',
                    'post_status'       => 'trash',
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1
                )
        );

    while( $prod_query->have_posts() ) : $prod_query->the_post();

        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'            =>  get_the_ID(),
            'post_status'   =>  'publish'
        ));

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse218859_trash_to_publish_on_activation' );
```

**Deactivate and delete it, after completion.**

Comment: error when try install PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Comment: You put the code into a file, i.e. named `wc-trash-recovery.php`, and then put the file in `/wp-content/plugins` directory, and then from WordPress admin panel > Plugins, you activated **WooCommerce Trash Recovery**. If is that your way, I'm afraid, I can't save you any more. Because it's the way of activating a sole plugin.

Comment: anyway thank you, sure your plugin work great, i wrong named it, i called it trash.php, reason for the error in installation

Comment: `trash.php` as a plugin file name can never cause an error like this. seems weird!